# The key container name 'bsn' does not exist

Tags: c#, assemblies, grammar, public-key

I'm trying to run the project of bsn-goldparser (https://code.google.com/p/bsn-goldparser/) and I have the next trouble:
Visual Studio shows me the next message : "Error   2   Cryptographic failure while signing assembly...The key container name 'bsn' does not exist..." .After hours searching, I have tryed the next:  I have edited all projects files and  I have removed the line bsn. But now, the error is it doesn't found libraries that are already added.  I need know more, but i don't known where I can read about this.
Thanks.

Comment: You can probably try [delayed signing](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=delay+signing+in+visual+studio). Some projects strongly-sign their assemblies, but usually the private key to do that is not published or included in source control.

Comment: Thanks. But I have checked the sign options and they are unselected in all projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is here:

[removing strongly signed from assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993835/removing-strongly-signed-from-assembly).

Besides, I have compiled the projects with framework 4.0, because they had been compiled with framework 3.5 client profile.